# Console pause c#

Tags: c#

In this code

```
Console.Write("Enter any number from 0 to 9:");
int k = Console.Read();
Console.Write("The ASCII code for it is:");
Console.WriteLine(k);
Console.Read();
```

after I input a number my console close instantly.
If I write this code

```
Console.Write("Enter any string:");
string k = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Your string is:");
Console.WriteLine(k);
Console.Read();
```

my console stops so I can see what I wrote.
Why is that happening?

Comment: You mean you don't want it to say hello?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you mean you want the program to exit? Or do you want the program to wait? Hover for a moment? Wait for a key press? Do you need to write `Hello` at all? Please be more specific.

Comment: I input any number ,and I want to Write back Hello and then wait.But the console close after I input a number and press enter.

Comment: I input a number,but it doesn't matter which one i just want the code to write Hello and then wait me to press enter and then to close.

Comment: I edited the post.I hope that now i made clear what i want to point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following instead of Console.ReadLine();

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

This will wait for your console to input any key before closing.

Answer (score 0):

ReadLine, Read etc. should work but you can also run it via Ctrl-F5 instead, which will keep the window open until you hit a key. Or remove the ReadLine at the end completely if you just want it to close.

Note Ctrl-F5 is running without debugging. If you're after breakpoints don't do this.

Although with your code you're only going to going to get the behaviour you expect from the .Read on line 2.

```
num=Console.Read();
```

I think it will be the ASCII code for the first 'character' of your number i.e. if you enter 322 it will just read 3 and the ASCII for 3 is 51, which will be what is assigned to num.

Comment: I just want it to stop.Doesn't matter that is in ASCII the num.

Comment: Then leave the Console.ReadLine waiting for Enter or run with Ctrl-F5?

Comment: Wait for enter then leave.